# Help with Bayesian model averaging

Tags: bayesian, model-averaging

I am new to statistical modelling and I need some help with Bayesian model averaging.
I have 3 models and I would like to derive a BMA of these models.

I am using the BIC estimate for the different models and a uniform prior probability of 0.33.

Model 1, BIC= 4420
Model 2, BIC= 3940
Model 3, BIC = 4325

I am stuck trying to calculate the **Posterior probability** for each model and I don’t know how to use that in **estimating the BMA**.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot derive the posterior probability from the BIC.

Comment: You could approximate $Pr(M_{i}|\mathbf{X})$ using the relative difference in BICs, as described in the answer to [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/249888).

Comment: @Durden, many thanks